# First time owing taxes. Is it okay to pay in pennies and sign in blood?

Tags: united-states

I plan on bringing in a satchel full of pennies, a nib-pen to draw my signature and initials over the documents, and a tack to draw blood for the ink. In today's state of personal security, isn't my DNA better than a plastic card for identification? Can, I be arrested for anything in my plans? Not that I care. I've served time before. Civilization is absurd, and I do everything I can to shorten my time with the rest of you.

Answer (score 3):

You can only pay [the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/payments/what-to-expect-when-you-pay-cash-at-an-irs-office) in USD bills and you can't pay in coins

> the number and denominations of U.S. bills